# PHP - insert same field into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

PHP - Inserting Into Xampp/ Mysql

iam making product database with insert php like this

```
  $save_sale = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale(no_receipt,no_confirm,time,date,day,total) values
         ('$_POST[no_receipt]',
          '$_POST[no_confirm]',
          '$hour_now',
          '$date_now',
          '$day_now',
          '$_POST[total]')")
         or die(mysql_error());
  $save_sale_detail =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale_detail(no_receipt,id_product,quantity,price,subtotal) values
         ('$_POST[no_receipt]',
          '$_POST[id_product]',
          '$_POST[quantity]',
          '$_POST[price]',
          '$_POST[subtotal]')")
         or die(mysql_error());
```

but it just save one transaction every time i submit multipple product order with different quantity, price and subtotal.
i was meaning something like in **sale** saving and create no_receipt and then **sale_detail** create no_receipt too following **sale**.
example :
         Sale

```
     No. Receipt  = 001
     No. Confirm  = 205850 <-- it just confirmation order
     hour         = 17.00
     date         = 31/08/2013
     day          = saturday
     total        = $770 <-- subtotal calculation

     sale_detail
     No. Receipt  = 001
     id_product   = 1 <-- let say it's a hat
     quantity     = 3
     price        = $150 <-- price by each product
     subtotal     = $450 <-- price * quantity
     ----- and come other product order ---
     sale_detail
     No. Receipt  = 001
     id_product   = 4 <-- let's say it's a glasses
     quantity     = 4
     price        = $80 <-- price by each product
     subtotal     = $320 <-- price * quantity
     ----- and come other.. ---------------
```

but i stuck and just can saving one transaction, if **sale _detail** success to saving, the **sale** still empty.

any help would be appreciate..

Comment: did you get any error..

Comment: I know you probably just creating the script and this will not answer your question. DO NOT post directly into MySQL make sure you clean your post before you insert data. That script will be easily injected for your info. :)

Comment: it's just a custom script than the original of mine,

Comment: In addition to SQL injection vulnerabilities, you are trusting the user to send the prices!  You should receive only the product ID and then look up the price from the database.  Think about it -- what if I just use Firebug and change the price to $0.01 for every item?

Comment: no.. the user it just click and add product data, i make the price field like ...<input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$price."> just before the image and name product

Comment: Yes but that `value` attribute can be changed once it is in the browser, that is my point.  You are taking the price posted by the user and just inserting it as though it is the verified price, which it certainly is not.

Comment: oh my, i should learn more about SQL than php then.. i was try to making it "cart checkout" to 2  table in my database.. but, thanks for the advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to POST the per-product details as an array.  In the markup you would use `<input name="id_product[]"..../>`

This will then be received in PHP as an array (`echo gettype($_POST['id_product'])` will output `array`).

Then you can loop through with `foreach ($_POST['id_product'] as $id)` or something else, and call your `INSERT INTO sale_detail...` query multiple times (once per loop iteration).

Note that you only want to put `[]` in the `name` attribute of the values that actually are per-item.  For example the `no_invoice` field is a single value, not an array, so you would just use `name="no_invoice"` and not `name="no_invoice[]"`.